# Consultas a API RESTFULL con Postman

Tags: api, postman, restful

¿Para que el frontend de una página web muestre los resultados que postman obtenga al llamar a una api restfull que me recomiendan hacer? Soy nuevo en esto y no se por donde empezar.

Comment: Postman es para la fase de desarrollo. Las peticiones post, get, put y demas las debe hacer tu front, por ejemplo, con jquery usas ajax, angular, httpClient, etc. Postman te sirve para que no tengas que escribir tanto código en el front antes de probar el backend. De echo, no ocupas el front con una api rest. (Para el desarrollo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder contestar a tu pregunta tenemos que remontarnos un poco al por que se dividió el backend del front end (antes se fusionaban ambos en el mismo proyecto y se trabajaban juntos).

La respuesta es por facilidad del desarrollador, al trabajar ambas cosas en el mismo proyecto era mas complicado agregar nuevas funcionalidades, ya que al ir tan de la mano si modificabas el front le pegabas un poco al back y viceversa y eso es una muy mala practica. Imagina eso hoy en día que los proyectos son tan robustos? tomaría demasiado tiempo y dinero.

Entendiendo lo anterior puedo responder tu pregunta, si quieres ver reflejada la información que trae tu back end dependerá mucho de la tecnología en la que estas desarrollando el proyecto. Ya que por ejemplo la manera de hacerlo en una aplicación android nativa, una hibrida o una web spa es diferente (aunque al final es el mismo principio, pintar tu json de respuesta en pantalla), lo que te recomiendo es ser mas especifico en tu pregunta como por ejemplo:
Como pintar en pantalla la respuesta de mi back end en Android Studio con java o como consumir mi api rest con angular y seguro encontras algo.

No podría responder tu pregunta como tal ahora por que realmente depende mas que nada de la tecnología que estas utilizando espero te sirva saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Diego!

Postman en realidad es un software para "probar" peticiones http. Si lo que quieres es hacer una llamada a una API dentro de tu app y usar esos datos, tendrás que hacerlo directamente en tu código.

Ya que no proporcionas cómo está estructurada tu app, intentaré explicar de una manera general:

Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es llamar a tu API y guardar esa respuesta dentro de una variable, la respuesta más común a la llamada (GET) a una API sería un JSON (que no es más que un Array lleno de información en formato texto). Al guardar esa respuesta en una variable, podrás usarla como si fuese un Array que tú mismo declaraste dentro de tu código y acceder a sus elementos y propiedades.

Una de las maneras más sencillas de interactuar con API's es con [Axios](https://axios-http.com/), puedes instalarlo en tu app dentro de la cónsola, escribiendo lo siguiente:

```
npm install axios
```

Y luego dentro de tu código tienes que importarlo como:

```
const axios = require('axios');
```

Si ya sabes hacer request dentro de Postman, entonces no te será difícil hacerlas dentro de tu código con Axios, sería algo así:

```
// Este sería el request como tal a tu API
axios.get('url') // "url" sería la URL de la API
  .then(function (response) {
    // Lo que está aquí abajo es lo que ocurre en caso de que la API responda con éxito, por ejemplo un console.log (el JSON que te envíe tu API va a ser la variable response)
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // Lo que está aquí abajo es lo que ocurre en caso de que la llamada a la API de como resultado un error
    console.log(error);
  })
```